# Veins can now "simulate cars without network cards" - Documentation?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Dear OMNET/Veins community,

I noticed in the [Changelog](http://veins.car2x.org/download/) under Veins v4.3 that there is now capability for simulating vehicles without network cards.

Would there be any documentation / or instructional material available to help the user take advantage of this new capability?

Thanks so much,

Van

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of this insofar as you can now remove the module simulating a network card (the *NIC* module) from a car without the simulation complaining (it used to throw an error, noting that simulating a VANET without network cards makes no sense).

This is useful if your cars communicate via a different method that Veins does not know about (for example, an oracle that always simple "knows" information), as opposed to simulating the wireless transmission of this information.